# Timber wordpress - include with varriables

Tags: wordpress-theming, timber

I have a `hero-block.twig`, which has the hero variable is set to fields.hero

```
{% set hero = fields.hero %}

{% for item in hero %}
 {{item.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to include the hero-block.twig to other twig field, with the hero is replaced with post.meta('hero'), but the hero doesn't return any value. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

```
{% include "block/hero-block.twig" with { hero : post.meta('hero') }  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `hero` in **hero-block.twig**, you currently always set it to `fields.hero`. You should add the logic so that `hero` can be overwritten.

```
{% set hero = hero ?? fields.hero %}
```

By using the null coalescing operator, you can check whether hero is passed in an include and use the passed `hero` value, or fall back to `fields.hero`.

If you only use the variable once, you can also directly us that in the for loop.

```
{% for item in hero ?? fields.hero %}
    {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```